# credit card to multiple paypal transfer in one transaction in rest api php is possible?

Tags: php, paypal

I want to make payment from credit card to 2 Paypal account users. 
sender will not create either Paypal account or merchant account, he will send payment using only credit card.

Thank you for a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel payments enable a sender to send a single payment to multiple receivers. For example, your application might be a shopping cart that enables a buyer to pay for items from several merchants with one payment. Your shopping cart allocates the payment to merchants that actually provided the items. PayPal then deducts money from the sender's account and deposits it in the receivers' accounts.

[image]

You've got two main options: use the [Mass Pay Api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/) or try out the new [Adaptive Payment Api.](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

The Adaptive Payments option gives you a lot more control over the payment and is the future direction of the Paypal APIs, so that's where i'd start if i were you. It supports SOAP, NVP, JSON and plain XML. MassPay has both a SOAP and NVP interface.

IPNs are a totally different subject:[Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)